# Javascript Single Page App - Azure Deployment VS code

Tags: javascript, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service, single-page-application

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-auth-code

I've followed this the tutorial linked above sucessfully, running it locally.

I can't figure out how to deploy into an App Service so I can host it in the cloud.

I would like deploy it through VS code and have installed the App Service extension.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

You can login to your account and then deploy the Appservice as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/deploy-nodejs-azure-app-service-with-visual-studio-code?tabs=bash)

1. From the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), type "create web" and select Azure App Service: Create New Web
2. Create a resource group
3. Deploy to Appservice

Comment: When I do that and open it in my browse it says "You do not have permission to view this directory or page" - is there a file I should be adding to the folder for deployment?

Comment: @MidnightFrost It seems you use windows webapp, so you should add web.config file, then try.